# Create a Key Filter from an External Data column

Tags: managed-metadata, filter, external-data, key-filter

I'm currently creating a Document management system in On-prem SP 2013 to store documents with specific meta data terms so the document library is easily searchable/filtered.

We have an external DB that contains a view with all of our customers names, I have created a external content type from this and a picker in the Document library that allows you to choose a customer from the DB and assign its value to a External Data column.

The issue I'm now having is that I'm unable to find a way to filter by the customer name/external data column in the same way i'm able to with Meta data terms.

Any help with how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. The only work around i currently have is to create each customer as a meta term, however as there is no option to sync terms with a DB this would be a nightmare to administer.

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot of current layout]